# android java add/sub weird decimal result

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to add float number but it's doesn't work well.

```
Result:
0.2
0.4
0.6
0.8
1.0
1.2
1.4000001
```

my code :

```
static public void add_order(Product d)
    {       
        Float tt = Float.parseFloat(text_price.getText().toString());       
        tt += Float.parseFloat(d.getPrice());
        text_price.setText(tt + "");
    }
```

any idea ?

Comment: some reading: http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

Comment: Generally when working with money or any other values where you simply can't afford letting the computer do mistakes, *don't* use float or double.

Comment: Can i have a exemple to convert a string number to BigDecimal pls?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) also `Can i have a exemple to convert a string number to BigDecimal pls` just use constructor with String argument like `new BigDecimal("12.34")`

Comment: The difference between float/double and BigDecimal is whether decimal fractions are specially supported. Float and double, for compactness and efficient hardware support, are based on binary fractions. BigDecimal, based on decimal fractions, is the right type to use if numbers that can be expressed as short, terminating decimal fractions are especially important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem like it is not working well to me, `float` is not made for exact results; do not use it in that context. Use an `int` or `long` and for example multiply by 100, then you have 2 digits that actually work.

From the terms in your code example I assume you're doing some currency work; if you have a requirement for different precisions, go for `BigDecimal`.